# C# async deadlock with HttpClient when called from a Xamarin event, why?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, httpclient, deadlock

I am experiencing a deadlock issue with HttpClient calls. I am guessing the deadlock is the result of my incomplete knowledge about async programming and I am doing something wrong. I have simplified the actual code into the example below, but I have maintained the same method call sequence and structure. I will be grateful for some insides on what could be causing the deadlock and suggestions on how to overcome this issue.

I created an extension class for HttpClient, which has the following methods:

```
//HttpClientExtension class
public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsyncCustom(this HttpClient client, Uri uri, HttpContent request, bool tryReauth)
{
    var originalResponse = await client.PostAsync(uri, request);
    var content = await originalResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if(tryReauth)
    {
        //check if session expired and login again
        var login = await App.Communication.Login();
        //throw exception with the reauth status
        if(login)
        {
            throw new AuthException(true);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AuthException(false);
        }
    }
}

public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsyncWithReauth(this HttpClient client, Uri uri, HttpContent request)
{
    return await PostAsyncCustom(client, uri, request, true);
}

public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsyncWithoutReauth(this HttpClient client, Uri uri, HttpContent request)
{
    return await PostAsyncCustom(client, uri, request, false);
}
```

This methods are used inside my Communication class which looks something like this:

```
//Communication class
//HttpClient is defined in contstructor
public async Task<bool> Login()
{
    //Define Uri and Request
    var response = await client.PostAsyncWithoutReauth(uri, request);
    //Check response status and return success/failure
    return true;
}

public async Task<bool> FetchData()
{
    //Define Uri and Request
    try
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsyncWithReauth(uri, request);
    }
    catch(AuthException ae)
    {
        //if reauth was successfull
        if(ae)
        {
            var newResponse = await client.PostAsyncWithoutReauth(uri, request);
            //Check newResponse status and return success/failure
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So what happens is that when an `AuthException` is thrown with status = true and `PostAsyncWithoutReauth` will be called, what happens is that the break-point inside `PostAsyncWithoutReauth` will be triggered, but upon continuation the break-point inside `PostAsyncCustom` which is called from the `PostAsyncWithoutReauth` never triggers. The code will just continue to "execute" until Task timeout exception will be triggered. So that's why I think it is a deadlock issue. I have tried setting the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on some of the calls, but the issue remained the same.

**Update:**

The `FetchData` method is called from the Xamarin.Forms ContentPage, where it is triggered by completed event on an Entry field:

```
Input.Completed += async (s, e) =>
{
    var status = await App.Communication.FetchData();
}
```

I would like to add that if instead the `PostAsyncWithoutReauth` call I replace it with `return await FetchData()`, this will not deadlock.

**Update #2:**
I simplified the code, so my `PostAsyncCustom` now looks like that:

```
public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsyncCustom(this HttpClient client, Uri uri, HttpContent request, bool tryReauth)
{
    var originalResponse = await client.PostAsync(uri, request);
    var content = await originalResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if(tryReauth)
    {
        return await PostAsyncCustom(client, uri, request, false);
    }
    return originalResponse;
}
```

What happens here is that the `client.PostAsync` will hang when called for the second time. I also tried to get rid of the recursion so I tested the code like that:

```
public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsyncCustom(this HttpClient client, Uri uri, HttpContent request, bool tryReauth)
{
    var originalResponse = await client.PostAsync(uri, request);
    var content = await originalResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if(tryReauth)
    {
        var secondReponse = await client.PostAsync(uri, request);
    }
    return originalResponse;
}
```

This will also hang when the `client.PostAsync` is called for the second time.

Update #3:

The "deadlock" finally throws an exception with stacktrace, which can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/1kCCrSs9).

Comment: How are you calling these methods?

Comment: *This methods are used inside my Communication class* and how is your communication class used? and how is that class used, etc.? My guess is at some point your doing a `.Result`?

Comment: Just a few pointers: Use a using statement for HttpResponseMessage(s) `using (var originalResponse = await client.PostAsync(...))` to make sure that it's properly disposed of and no connections remain open. I would also strongly suggest not using exceptions to dictate logic flows. Exception handling is slow, expensive, and when you are using it like you're doing it makes it extremely hard to tell when an actual error is occurring.

Comment: Where are you getting your HttpClient from?  https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: How does the authentication code work? Do you have the code?

Comment: I update the question with additional data.

Comment: Does it compile? I thought we could not await a method in a catch closure.

Comment: @EricMagers, thank you for your pointers, I added the exception throwing later, in the begining I tired to recall the client.PostAsync inside my PostAsyncCustom method. I then tried to move the client recall back into my call stack to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Neil, the HttpClient instance is a property on my Communication class. I set it inside the Communication class constructor and then just call it. Based on the comments here, this is bad practice, since I should be making a new instance (with using) for every call?

Comment: @Daniel You can await in a catch block, since C# 6.

Comment: @Daniel, yes it compiles, I use await inside catch statements on several occasions.

Comment: Whether you should use a shared `HttpClient` or construct a new one every time is not an easy thing to answer, you need to google the topic. If you don't want to do that, stay with a shared instance.

Comment: No Denis, creating and `using` is exactly what you should NOT be doing.  You will end up with socket exhaustion.  You should create one (or very few) HttpClient instances for the whole application.

Comment: @mortb I don't understand the question? The authentication code is another POST call to the WS.

Comment: You should stay with shared client objects, only create new objects (and share those as well) if you need different configuration, such as default headers and so on for different sites/apis.

Comment: Have you tried shaving off (commenting out) bits and pieces bit by bit, to find out at least one factor that triggers the problem?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I tried that, so I came to the conclusion that the problem is that once the breakpoint inside PostAsyncWithoutReauth is triggered, but the first line inside PostAsyncCustom is not executed then. I will do some more digging.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use async/await for your single-line methods that simply return a task from another method call, so the `PostAsyncWith(out)Reauth` methods, you can safely remove both `async` and `await` here. This will not solve your deadlock problem though.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I added another update, the problem looks to be the second .PostAsync call on the HttpClient.

Comment: Can you post the exception type and message as well?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Exception type: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException, Exception message: A task was canceled.