# async event handler sometimes hangs in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm having an async event handler that is triggered in my input field whenever the text changes. This is a Xamarin.Forms application and I am using the event handler `TextChanged` in order to simulate "over-type" functionality in my Entry, as for example writing the text when insert key in active. However, this sometimes causes the application to deadlock after the await Task.Yield() call. This call is needed to get the correct behavior, otherwise the caret doesn't go into the correct position after the call is executed. I can't figure out why does the code hand and how to fix this issue, so any help/advice will be appreciated. I'm guessing the issue has to do with my insufficient async programming knowledge.

```
private static async void OnOvertypeTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: START {guid.ToString()}");
        var entry = sender as CustomEntry;
        if (entry.IsOvertypeRunning)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            entry.IsOvertypeRunning = true;
        }
        try
        {
            entry.TextChanged -= OnOvertypeTextChanged;
            //Update value as in overtype mode
            var oldVal = e.OldTextValue;
            var newVal = e.NewTextValue;
            int? carret = null;
            //If new string is longer, we should go into overtype mode, otherwise ignore it
            if (newVal?.Length > oldVal?.Length)
            {
                var i = entry.CursorPosition;
                var overtyped = oldVal.Substring(0, i) + newVal[i] + ((oldVal.Length > (i + 1)) ? oldVal.Substring(i + 1) : "");
                entry.Text = overtyped;
                carret = i + 1;
                //Check if new overtyped value is longer than max allowed size
                if (entry.OvertypeLength != -1 && entry.Text.Length > entry.OvertypeLength)
                {
                    var cut = entry.Text.Substring(0, entry.OvertypeLength);
                    //If new text would be longer, then cut it
                    entry.Text = cut;
                    if (carret >= cut.Length)
                    {
                        carret = cut.Length;
                    }
                }
            }
            //For some reason, this is needed...
            if (carret != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: WAITING {guid.ToString()}");
                await Task.Yield();
                Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: DONE_WAITING {guid.ToString()}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: SETTING_CURSOR {guid.ToString()} @ {carret.Value.ToString()}");
                entry.CursorPosition = carret.Value;
                Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: CURSOR_SET {guid.ToString()}");
            }
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: DONE {guid.ToString()}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: ERROR {guid.ToString()}", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            entry.IsOvertypeRunning = false;
            entry.TextChanged += OnOvertypeTextChanged;
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}: END {guid.ToString()}");
        }
}
```

So what will happen is that everything will be working normally, just after a few successfull focus/unfocus events on the Entry, it will hang.

So the logging will produce something like:

```
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: START bba4b754-8f22-4a14-ae28-8536d3a1e3d1
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: WAITING bba4b754-8f22-4a14-ae28-8536d3a1e3d1
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: DONE_WAITING bba4b754-8f22-4a14-ae28-8536d3a1e3d1
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: SETTING_CURSOR bba4b754-8f22-4a14-ae28-8536d3a1e3d1 @ 14
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: CURSOR_SET bba4b754-8f22-4a14-ae28-8536d3a1e3d1
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: DONE bba4b754-8f22-4a14-ae28-8536d3a1e3d1
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: END bba4b754-8f22-4a14-ae28-8536d3a1e3d1
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: START 71bf9809-6217-4d73-94df-817042a251b9
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: WAITING 71bf9809-6217-4d73-94df-817042a251b9
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: DONE_WAITING 71bf9809-6217-4d73-94df-817042a251b9
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: SETTING_CURSOR 71bf9809-6217-4d73-94df-817042a251b9 @ 14
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: CURSOR_SET 71bf9809-6217-4d73-94df-817042a251b9
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: DONE 71bf9809-6217-4d73-94df-817042a251b9
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:26: END 71bf9809-6217-4d73-94df-817042a251b9
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:31: START f9fca969-e141-4a07-968d-e32616323995
[0:] 18. 12. 2018 17:57:31: WAITING f9fca969-e141-4a07-968d-e32616323995
```

And after that application becomes unresponsive and displays the message "Application X is not responding..."

The same async "deadlocks" were happenning to me when calling HttpClient services as described in [CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970031/c-sharp-async-deadlock-with-httpclient-when-called-from-a-xamarin-event-why)

I am guessing the issues could be similar?

Comment: Use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async()=>{}); put code in this

Comment: The whole code inside event handler or? @AditKothari

Comment: Yes in event handler you can write this

Comment: @DenisVitez Why are using `Task.Yield()` that seems to be the issue? Nothing else in your method is async, so why not just run it synchronously. `Task.Yield()` isn't meant to be used to keep a UI responsive.

Comment: @JSteward I was using the Task.Yield() to get the correct behavior (so the cursor did place in the correct spot). However I found out that it is not necessary to use it, so I tweaked my code to get rid of this and it doesn't lock anymore. But I still don't understand why the locking occurred in the first place :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @JSteward kindly noted, the use of Task.Yield() is not necessary and since it was the reason behind application hanging, this is now resolved. The updated code for the OnTextChanged handler, that simulates overtype mode and how to easily use it with C# extensions for Entry class can be found here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/143533/is-it-possible-to-have-overtype-functionality-in-entry

I hope this will help someone in the future :)